# How can i encrypt a function or its contents in a php class?

Tags: php, encryption

How can i encrypt a function or its contents in a php class ?

e.g. Take a look at below class, i would like to encrypt the function test1() so the code inside will never be revealed but executes as normal

```
class test
{
 var $x;
 var $y;

 function test1()
 {
  return $this->x; 

 }

 function test2()
 {
  return $this->y; 

 }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the code? In most cases it is not very useful to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The code can't really be hidden from someone that has access to the file, but it can be [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). There are too many alternatives, try google 'php obfuscate'.

Keep in mind that even though it will be harder, it will by no means be impossible for a skilled coder to quickly discern what happens in your code (especially if it's as simple as the example you provided).

Answer (score 0):

Extract test1 to base class:

```
abstract class testBase {
  function test1(){
    return $this->x;
  }
}
```

Encode it with http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/. Then use testBase as test parent:

```
class test extends testBase {
  public $x;
  public $y;

  function test2(){
    return $this->y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sam but my class already have a parent class.. and php doesnt support multiple inheritance.. does it?
e.g
class test extends testparent

Comment: It does not. But it does support multiple interfaces I believe